# Rails: I'm having a problem with inherited associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's the problem I'm having:
https://gist.github.com/1003813

or

Say you have a derived class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ThisThing
 include ThatThing

 [...]

end

class OurUser < User
 set_table_name 'users'

 [...]

end
```

I need some associations, for example:

```
belongs_to :friend, 
        :class_name => 'User',
        :foreign_key => :friend_of
```

The problem is that if this is declared in the User class, the friend of an OurUser will be a User, and will not have any of the extra methods included in OurUser. And of course you don't know the correct class name when the User class is written.

I need some suggestons on how I can make it so OurUser will have a .friend of the correct class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a module with all the shared behaviour and use the Module#included hook to define your associations dynamically at include. i.e.:

```
module SharedBehaviour
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      set_table_name 'users'         

      belongs_to :friend, :class_name => base.name, :foreign_key => :friend_of

      include ThisThing
      include ThatThing

      # other class method calls go here (validations, etc)
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # shared class methods go here
  end

  # shared instance methods go here
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  inclde SharedBehaviour
end

class OtherUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SharedBehaviour
end
```